# Difficulty shooting in high ISO with my Canon 5D Mark II

Tags: high-iso

While trying to shooting at 2500 ISO in a dark music jam, when I push the shutter it just stays open, the plus/minus exposure dial through the lens flips to far left, and I have to change the setting to make the shutter finish.. then no shot... do I have wrong settings somewhere that is causing this.? I have a 35mm 1:1.4 lens attached...Canon

Comment: In which mode do you take the photo?

Comment: Sounds like the mirror lockup feature is turned on.

Comment: Are you stating that, if the only thing you change right now is the ISO (let's say, back to 100), this behavior goes away. But, if you change the ISO back to 2500, this behavior appears?

Comment: This could be several things... can you provide more info on specifically which shooting mode (M, Tv, Av, or P, etc.) AND also which metering mode (Evaluative, Partial, Spot, or Center-Weighted) you are using (see:  https://support-sg.canon-asia.com/contents/SG/EN/8200355300.html )  For a low-light concert, I'd probably use "Partial" (which only uses metering zones near the center of the frame and ignores the rest).   Concerts often have "black" backgrounds ... making the camera think it needs a much longer exposure to bring up details in the black background.

Comment: “*do I have wrong settings somewhere that is causing this*“.we don’t know what your setting are.  Are you taking a meter reading and verifying that there is enough light to give you a shutter speed that is  not several seconds.

Comment: "dark music jam" is some of the stickiest jam there is.

Comment: Unsolicited concert advice: Manual mode, meter in in the beginning, and just occasionally do a manual variation (some lower ISO shots to capture motion and get more dynamic range, some narrower aperture shots for clarity, some higher iso and faster shutter ones to get good motion freeze...) The lighting situation does not change much on average - and the dynamic changes are much too hectic for any meter to deal with anyway...)

Answer (score 2):

2500 ISO is not actually very high. Indoor lighting is much dimmer than people usually assume (human vision is remarkably adaptive). In a "dark music jam", it is very likely that even if you have your aperture wide open at f/1.4, a long shutter speed is required.

In other words, everything seems working as designed and expected.

Answer (score 1):

Well, without knowing anything about your Canon settings beyond ISO, there could be several culprits:

1) You have a Canon SLR and have turned on "Mirror lockup" so depressing the shutter once flips up the mirror, turning the viewfinder black. If you press the shutter release a second time, the camera will take the photo and then flip the mirror back down again. [Here's the Canon KB entry on 5D Mk II mirror lockup](https://support.usa.canon.com/kb/index?page=content&id=ART103739&cat=2764B&actp=LIST) -- so many different behaviors.

2) You are in Full Auto or Aperture Priority mode and ISO 2500 isn't nearly high enough (easily possible in a dark studio). The camera is selecting a long exposure time and you are cutting it off by changing modes before it is done.

3) (Less likely given your description): You have set the shutter speed set to "B" for "Bulb" exposure. The shutter stays open as long as you hold down the shutter release.

Comment: There's a subtle clue in the title as to which model ;-)

Comment: Haha! Totally missed that.